# Sorting events based on their start date

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display events list on the page in a way such that the events will be sorted according to their start date but the events which have already passed should appear at the bottom of the list, currently I'm using this query to sort events but this one is not effective as its showing the events which have already occured at the top

```
Event.select("id , name, date_begin, date_end, user_id, moderator_name, moderator_phone, contact_phone, time_zone, url").order("date_begin asc")
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: I've seen sorting like this attempted before and it wasn't fun - good luck sir/madam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@upcoming, @past = Event.order('date_begin DESC').partition{ |e| e[:date_begin] >= DateTime.now }
```

You will get two arrays. First of upcoming events, and second for already passed events.

UPDATE:

to reverse the order, simply use:

```
@upcoming, @past = Event.order('date_begin DESC').partition{ |e| e[:date_begin] >= DateTime.now }
@past.reverse!
```

Comment: Awesome, but what if we want both sorted in different ways?

Comment: It seems from your question that you want both of them to be in the same sort way

Comment: I want both of them sorted in different way, is it possible here in this query?

Comment: I don't think so. What about sorting it after the query?

Comment: thanks buddy, you saved my day, I've sorted it after the query using this `@past = @past.sort_by(&:date_begin).reverse`
Thanks again! :)

Comment: You can do `@past.sort_by!(&:date_begin).reverse`. With `!`.

Comment: what is the difference between two of them?

Comment: It usually affects the object itself, without making `@past =`. But in this case, I see now there is no difference.

Comment: Hey! if you just want to reverse it, there is no need to sort again, since in your query you sort it. you just need `@past.reverse!`...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you split your query into 2 parts, events coming up and past events. This improves readability and usability.

```
@upcoming_events = Event.where('date_begin >= ?', DateTime.now)
@past_events = Event.where('date_begin < ?', DateTime.now)
```

You can be more OOP by adding these as methods in your model.

Comment: Can you please help me get through this? How to split it into two parts?

Comment: @RSB Sure, do you want to use Active Records?

Comment: I'm ok with both active record and sql query

Comment: can we do it in a single query?

Comment: @RSB What do you want to get out of adding them to a single query?

Answer (score 1):

I think your queries should be like this.

```
@upcoming_events = Event.where('date_end >= ?', DateTime.now).order('date_begin DESC')
@passed_events = Event.where('date_end < ?', DateTime.now)
```

Comment: can we do it in a single query?